# Would a question asking for English terms used to designate some aspects of the Spanish language be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

In a question in [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) someone is asking [what are the English terms used to designate the Spanish verb tenses](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26407/12637). Some people (myself included) have closed the question as off-topic, because we cannot make translations from Spanish to other languages. But other people are asking to reopen the question as it is about the Spanish language.

We have [another question about the Spanish names of the same tenses](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1067/12637) the OP asked about, but that question seems not to answer theirs as they are asking for the English terms.

So I would like to ask you: would such question asking for English terms used to designate the Spanish verb tenses be on topic here?

Answer (score 3):

IMO, as you're asking about field specific jargon, a more specific site would be more appropriate. Normal conversational English may not have terms for every Spanish grammatical term, but the jargon of *linguistics* would. Asking for translations of linguistics terminology is something that would best be asked at the [Linguistics site](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

And in the same way, if anyone wants to know the English translation of some Spanish legal terms, please point them to the [Law site](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Etc. etc. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some questions might be on topic at more than one SE site. Yes, asking for help identifying the correct English word for something is on topic here. As curiousdannii pointed out, it might also be on topic at some other sites.

Choose what you believe to be the most relevant site, and post your question there. If you do not get an answer, and you want to try another site, ask for migration, or else delete the original before re-asking the question on the other site. See: “[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? – Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/171321)”, an article from the Stack Exchange FAQ.